# How to manually check rows on screen, adding values in a new column?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know if it could be possible to print one row (specific fields) on the screen, then ask for a boolean value, then add this value in the corresponding field in a new column.

For example, I have a dataframe

```
Name     Age   Job
Alexandra 24  Student
Michael   42  Lawyer
John      53  Data Analyst
...
```

I would like to print on the screen rows, checking them one by one.
So I should have:

```
Alexandra Student
```

then a command that asks if `Alexandra` is female. Since Alexandra is a female, I should put `True` (input value) as value in a new column, called `Sex`.
Then I move to the next row:

```
Michael Lawyer
```

Since `Michael` is not a female, I should put `False` in the `Sex` column.
Same for `John`.

At the end, my expected output would be:

```
Name     Age   Job               Sex 
Alexandra 24  Student           True
Michael   42  Lawyer            False
John      53  Data Analyst      False
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this with `df.to_records` that as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues/45695288#45695288) is the fastest when iterating over rows:

```
sexs=[True if str(input(f'{row[1]} {row[3]}\nIs female?\n')).lower()=='true'  else False for  row in df.to_records()]

df['Sex']=sexs
print(df)
```

Or, to avoid that conditional `True if str(input(f'{row[1]} {row[3]}\nIs female?\n')).lower()=='true'  else False`, in view of the fact that you only will input `'True'` or `'False'`, you can try:

```
import ast
sexs=[ast.literal_eval(str(input(f'{row[1]} {row[3]}\nIs female?\n'))) for row in df.to_records()]

df['Sex']=sexs
print(df)
```

And if you want to keep the inputs as strings `'True'` or `'False'`, you could try:

```
sexs=[input(f'{row[1]} {row[3]}\nIs female?\n') for row in df.to_records()]

df['Sex']=sexs
```

Output of all the above options:

```
>>>Alexandra Student
>>>Is female?
True

>>>Michael Lawyer
>>>Is female?
False

>>>John Data Analyst
>>>Is female?
False

df

        Name  Age           Job    Sex
0  Alexandra   24       Student   True
1    Michael   42        Lawyer  False
2       John   53  Data Analyst  False
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work. It iterates through the rows using a for loop.

```
df['Sex'] = np.NaN

for i in range(len(df)):
    sex = input('Is {} {} a female? '.format(df.iloc[i,0],df.iloc[i,2]))
    df.iloc[i,3] = sex
```

Answer (score 0):

Iteration in Pandas is an anti-pattern and is something you should only do when you have exhausted every other option. By iteration, I mean using functions such as `iterrows` and `itertuples` that run in native Python.

I'm not quite sure what your mechanism is to determine the gender. But the best way for this problem is using a multi column apply function.

```
df['Sex'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: find_gender(row['Name'], row['Job']),    
    axis=1
)
```

In your `find_gender` function, you can write your logic based on the name and job (as you have stated in your question). In this function, you will have to return a Boolean to apply it to the row.